# How to create a Telegram Bot (python) that will fetch message reaction count?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to build a telegram bot on replit that will fetch the reaction count on the messages of the group (to later do a ranking of the 10 messages with the most reactions on them), but I can't find a library that has something like `reactionCount` inside it.

I have all my code ready except this, I tried with telethon and python-telegram-bot, but I can't find how to get the reaction count.

So my question is, which telegram library for Python, is supporting `reactionCount` or something similar ?

If someone has a solution for this, I'd be glad.

(and to clarify again so no-one closes my question for nothing again, I don't want people to give me code, or I don't have a problem in my code, my code is ready to work I just need a library that will fit my needs)

I tried using telethon and python-telegram-bot, but I can't find something related to "reaction count" inside the documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No python library can support reading message reactions via a Telegram bot since the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not support this functionality.

Userbots can do that and you can use `telethon` to code a userbot. Userbots do not use the Bot API.